# How to pass complex type data on Ajax binding

Tags: telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

Telerik ASP.NET MVC Q2 2011

I have a grid which is Ajax bound:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<IUser>()
                .Name("UsersGrid")
                .DataBinding(binding => binding.Ajax().Select("UsersGridSelect", "User", new { area = "Admin" }))
                .ClientEvents(events => events.OnDataBinding("onGridRefresh"))
     ...
     ...
```

This is my onGridRefresh handler:

```
function onGridRefresh(e)
{
    var modelData =
    {
        Username:       $('#SearchModel_Username').val(),
        FirstName:      $('#SearchModel_FirstName').val(),
        LastName:       $('#SearchModel_LastName').val(),   
        IsLocked:       $('#SearchModel_IsLocked').is(':checked'),
        ClientId:       $('#SearchModel_ClientId').val(),
        UserCode:       $('#SearchModel_UserCode').val(),
        ExpireDateFrom: $('#SearchModel_ExpireDateFrom').val(),
        ExpireDateTo:   $('#SearchModel_ExpireDateTo').val()
    };

    e.data = { searchModel: modelData };
}
```

And this is my controller:

```
[GridAction]
public ActionResult UsersGridSelect(UserSearchModel searchModel)
{
    IList<IUser> userList = searchModel == null ? new List<IUser>() : _repository.GetUsers(searchModel);

    return View(new GridModel(userList));
}
```

This setup does not work, I know...  But at least it demonstrates what I am after.
When I pass in my values as seperate parameter it works:

```
public ActionResult UsersGridSelect(string Username, string Firstname, string LastName,....)
```

But I would prefere to pass it in as an object.  Is there any way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use
`e.data = modelData` 
it will bind correctly.

Comment: Tried that already - did not work.  If you do so the question is what type you need to declare on the handler method.  Type 'UserSearchModel'  does not work.  Parameter 'searchModel' is always null in that case.

Comment: I'm not sure what to say. I am doing a very similar thing using a CalendarModel with properties StartDate and EndDate, and passing them in onDataBinding. I am able to use my custom type as the only parameter and those two properties are binding correctly to my model object. I would say post your view and UserSearchModel and maybe that will reveal something about the problem.